# Read location from list python

Tags: python, console

I am programming a python game that is supposed to run in the console. Here is the code so far:

```
#!python

import getpass

a = ""
rv = ""
playerLoc = []
meU= 0
meD= 0
meL= 0
meR= 0

# rv is used as a spae taker. 
# The Me... variables are used to store the players location, MeU is up, meD is down, so     on so forth.

while a != "q":
    a = getpass.getpass("")
    if a=="w":
        meU = meU + 1
    elif a=="a":
        meL = meL + 1
    elif a=="d":
        meR = meR + 1
    elif a=="s":
        meD = meD + 1
    elif a=="q":
        rv = ""
    elif a=="":
        rv = ""
    elif a==" ":
        rv = ""
    else:
        print "%Not A Command%"
while a !="q":
    playerLoc.append(meU)
    playerLoc.append(meD)
    playerLoc.append(meL)
    playerLoc.append(meR)
```

I am wondering how to display the players coordinates in a grid on the screen. Note I am not using curses or PyGame. I researched this topic and cannot find any answers. Remember this is not a GUI game and is in-console. I want the graphics to be like in snake or invaders or something like that. I hope this helps anyone else with the same problem. I am using the getpass module for invisible WASD pressing, although they do push the enter key. I tried using an asterisk '*' as the character and ran into another problem of how to dynamically move the player throughout the screen. I researched this for 2 weeks and have not found any answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Note I am not using curses or PyGame

You should start. `curses` is exactly what you need. Unless you know what kind of terminal the user is using, you can't reliably print text anywhere but at the bottom of the screen. If you do know what terminal the user has, you can use control codes and escape sequences, but using `curses` is still helpful because it gives you a nicer way to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar when making a hangman game, the only difference for you is that you need to display an X character at a certain position on the screen.  You could do this with a 2D array outlining what is where on your "screen"

First of all, if you are on windows, you should call `os.system('cls')` at the beginning of your draw() method that you should call continuously (in your while loop), and then you will print the entire 2d array to the screen.

2, if you do a 2D array to represent your map, then the origin is usually in the top left meaning that your positions will all be positive and higher x numbers will be on the right of the screen and higher y numbers will be on the bottom of the screen.

3, When the user enters a key maybe from `input()` or `raw_input()` depending on your version of python, you want to move his position up down left or right in the 2d array

Let me know what you want help with and i can elaborate